# Slight issue with my jQuery image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am (and have been for several hours) trying to get a image slider on this page I am attempting to make. I am burnt out. I really need help. Below is the page source. I am guessing the mixup is within there and not the js or css. Or maybe there are too many referenced style sheets? Or the order that things are in? I have literally copied and pasted the code from a tutorial site and still I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it won't run. Please I need help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>OUTER LIMIT MEDIA SOLUTIONS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bjqs.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/standardize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">


<!-- load jQuery and the plugin -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body class="body index clearfix">
  <div class="container _container container-1 clearfix">
    <div class="element element-1"></div>
    <header class="_container clearfix">
      <img class="outer-limit-logo" src="imG/OUTER-LIMIT-LOGO-IMPROV.svg">
      <div class="contact">CONTACT</div>
      <div class="the-work">WORK</div>
      <div class="about">ABOUT      </div>
    </header>
  </div>

<div id="container">


      <!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
      <div id="banner-slide">

        <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
        <ul class="bjqs">
          <li><a href=""><img src="img/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></a></li>
          <li><img src="img/banner02.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
          <li><img src="img/banner03.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption"></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

      </div>
      <!-- End outer wrapper -->

      <!-- attach the plug-in to the slider parent element and adjust the settings as required -->
      <script class="secret-source">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
            animtype      : 'slide',
            height        : 320,
            width         : 620,
            responsive    : true,
            randomstart   : true
          });

        });
      </script>

    </div>






  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="container _container container-2 clearfix">
    <div class="element element-2"></div>
    <div class="element element-3"></div>
    <div class="element element-4"></div>
    <div class="element element-5"></div>
    <div class="element element-6"></div>
    <div class="element element-7"></div>
    <div class="element element-8"></div>
    <div class="element element-9"></div>
    <div class="element element-10"></div>
    <div class="element element-11"></div>
    <div class="element element-12"></div>
    <div class="element element-13"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="_container _container-4 clearfix">
    <p class="text text-1">OUTER LIMIT MEDIA SOLUTIONS</p>
    <p onClick="window.location='mailto: info@outerlimitkw.com';" class="text text-2">INFO@OUTERLIMITKW.COM</p>
    <p class="text text-3">MAZAYA TOWER #1, 12TH FLOOR</p>
    <p class="text text-4">KHALID BIN AL WALEED ST.</p>
    <p class="text text-5">AL MURGAB, KUWAIT</p>
    <div class="container _container container-3 clearfix">
      <img class="facebook-outer-limit" src="imG/facebook-outer-limit.svg">
      <img class="instagram-outer-limit" src="imG/instagram-outer-limit.svg">
      <img class="linkedin-outer-limit" src="imG/linkedin-outer-limit.svg">
      <img class="twitter-outer-limit" src="imG/twitter-outer-limit.svg">
      <img class="google-plus-outer-limit" src="imG/google-plus-outer-limitt.svg">
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the tuto you were following?, just to check it and compare it with your work. A little advice, try to make an order and keep it. All the images put it into some directory (eg. "/images"), the same with the stylesheets (eg. "/css"), and all the other stuff.

When you make sure all it's in the right place, check every reference you made over the HTML, try to put every CSS in fewer files, if it's not absolutely necessary to separate it.

When you're done, I suggest you to check by step, to achieve lower goals each to find/debug where all this went wrong.

I have a guess, check if the demo.css is where should be. And then to the script, I believe there's NO class property to that element (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp class property apparently doesn't exists for that tag), try deleting it and replacing it with type="text/javascript" and move it to the bottom of the file...

Hope this helps!

PS: REMAINDER!, if you reference something from one folder to another in the same level, just make sure to add the dots before the slash (../), because you need to access the parent level to access the other folder. The same applies if you have several levels of folders just repeat the dots and slash as many times you need, but dude, don't abuse about it. As less levels it's better, always keep it simple and modulated.

Comment: Thank you for responding @Juanechomon! I got the tut from, [link]http://www.basic-slider.com/ . I think I kind of understand what you are saying. :-/

Comment: I checked it back and forth. I saved the code from the demo, then stripped it of everything but the one part i wanted. then implanted the bare bones code into my site and I have one photo off to the left with, Prev, Next, 1, 2, 3 in below it in linked text. Thats it. I tried to logically reverse engineer this thing.